# attaching a client process in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am working with postgresql 9.4.0 source using eclipse(indigo version) in ubuntu 14.04. I am facing a problem of attaching a client process to postgresql server.

I am following the steps given in this link https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse#Debugging_PostgreSQL_from_Eclipse

I am running both the eclipse and the client under the same user which is ravi.

following images shows the information regarding the debug configuration and the run configuration in eclipse.

[image: Details of the debug configuration]

[image: details of run configuration]

I am using the command "select pg_backend_pid()" in the client to attach it to the server.

but I am getting the following error everytime I am doing this.

**Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/socket/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/recv.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.**

Is the above error related something to my OS(ubuntu 14.04) or the eclipse itself, or am I not attaching the client process properly or is there something wrong with the installation of postgres itself.

kindly help.

Comment: Also posted to pgsql-hackers mailing list, see thread http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOh57xE5WSkksbE1UaMQTsvTH1L5BnpeknUrC3rNgawAeUKmMg@mail.gmail.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got past the issue mentioned on pgsql-hackers, as your screenshot shows a partially obscured debug session attached to a `postgres` backend, with a stack visible.

This is simply a "debugging C programs 101" issue: you don't have the source code for eglibc on your system, and the top stack frame is in eglibc. So Eclipse can't show you the source code. This doesn't matter unless you're interested in the details of what exactly eglibc was doing - and since it's probably just in a syscall, you most like are not interested.

Go further back in the stack to the first frame within PostgreSQL its self and it should show you the relevant PostgreSQL source line(s). If it doesn't you might have to set up your source path. Or just set whatever breakpoints you want and continue execution, since you're probably just stopped in a socket read call anyway.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but I could not get you, how do we go back to the first frame?  and could you mention how do we set the source path, I think that's the error.

Comment: @user3037781 You cannot set the source path to sources you do not have. You almost certainly do not have the eglibc sources. Nor do you need them. This error does not matter, because you do not care about eglibc. Jump to a higher stack frame. I use gdb directly, not via Eclipse, so I cannot tell you exactly how, but if I had to guess I'd say you scroll down, then double click on the stack frame of interest.

Comment: @user3037781 So under `Thread[1]` where it says `__libc_recv()` (that's a system call) then `recv()` etc - those are *stack frames*, i.e. nested function calls. They're listed from deepest to shallowest, so "main" is usually at the bottom. Each frame shows the exeutable or library it's part of, like "libc" or "postgres". Find the first one with "postgres" and double click on it to see where you're at in the program. I think you need to study the basics of debugging programs, as this is really the very basic beginnings.

Comment: sir, I followed your recent instruction, I went through the stack , and double click on postgresmain, then I was at the program postgres.c. Is that it ?? is it correct what I am doing.

Comment: @ravikiran Without having some idea what you are attempting to accomplish with this debugging session I could not possibly say. It sounds like you found a stack frame with source, anyway.

Comment: sir, I want to know how the join algorithm works in postgresql, for that I created a database , and created two tables in that, I found out the pid of that client, and used it to attach to the eclipse, could you tell how do we go about from now as I found out the stack frame, I just want to know whether the procesure which I am following now is correct or not

Comment: @ravikiran if you're attempting to step through the code then yes. Now go read some documentation on debugger use - step into/step over, breakpoints, stack traces, variable inspection etc. Honestly a debugger is NOT the way to study joins ... reading the source code and comments is.